# How to define the local variable of for...of loop using property accessor

Tags: javascript, for-of-loop

Saw this short paragraph from MDN JavaScript reference page on [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement, at around the end of Description section, it says:

> You can use destructuring to assign multiple local variables, or use a property accessor like **for (x.y of iterable)** to assign the value to an object property.

What does it mean? You can't have `x.y` syntax for defining the *local variable* in a `for...of` statement.
I tried this verbatimly in a short script file using node. Error message was `ReferenceError: x is not defined`

What I'd missed?

Comment: what did you miss ... defining x? try adding `const x = {};` before your for loop - interesting syntax though, can't see a use for it :p

Comment: As I understand, using `for (x.y of iterable)` will in every iteration set `y` property of `x` variable to be element of iterable. If you want to do that, you must first define `x` as empty object and then use it in `for` loop. Thing is that you can't initialize empty object in `for...of` definition and set it's property to be element of iterable.

Comment: @JaromandaX Wow, I'm so stupid. Thanks. So you can define a variable before hand, it'll just assign the values of each iteration to that variable, and the variable will have the value of the last iteration at the end. Okay, got it.

Comment: to be clear, it'll assign the value to the `y` property of `x` ... not to `x` - so any object will do, I just showed the simplest solution

Comment: @MilosStojanovic Yeah, Thanks for confirming. I tried it, doesn't need to be empty. If, for example, `x.z` already exist, it'll just add a `y` to `x` of value of each iteration. I think what I was not getting before, is that it's not necessary to use `const` or `let` to initialize a variable inside for...of, you can provide existing ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can use destructuring to assign multiple local variables,

This means that we can destructure the array of object in the for loop.

**For example,**

```
const iterable = [{a:'1', b:'10'}, {a:'2', b:'20'}, {a:'3', b:'30'}];

for (let {a, b} of iterable) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}
```

> or use a property accessor like for (x.y of iterable) to assign the
> value to an object property.

This means that we can use property accessor to assign the value from the array to our object's property.

**For example,**

```
const iterable = [{a:'1', b:'10'}, {a:'2', b:'20'}, {a:'3', b:'30'}];
let obj = {iterateValue:'', anyOtherValue:'Anything'}
// let obj = {}
// can be an empty object 
for (obj.iterateValue of iterable) {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

**You can't have x.y syntax for defining the local variable in a for...of statement.**

You need to define the object x before the for loop. Not in the `for...of statement`.

**ReferenceError: x is not defined**

This error means you have not defined x and trying to use it. You need to define it before the for loop.

Comment: You don't have to initialize property you will use on object before `for...of` loop. That object can be empty if you want.

Comment: Yes, definitely I have updated the answer.